# Error: System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting the error.  Here's my function:

```
public List<PlainBrgMetric> GetPlainBrgMetricProgram(long programLOBID) 
{
    var query = _context.metrics.Join(_context.universals,
                                      m => m.metricID,
                                      u => u.orderByAsc,
                                     (metric, universal) => new 
                                     {
                                         metric.metricID,
                                         metric.programLOBID,
                                         metric.label,
                                         universal.groupValue1
                                     }).ToList();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: "I'm getting the error" - what error? (And please reformat your code to be more readable...)

Comment: Fundamentally though, you're trying to return a list of anonymous type objects when you're meant to be returning a `List<PlainBrgMetric>`. Did you mean `new PlainBrgMetric { ... }` instead of `new { ... }` perhaps?

Comment: Or perhaps return List<dynamic>

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, because here:

```
(metric, universal) => new 
                       {
                           metric.metricID,
                           metric.programLOBID,
                           metric.label,
                           universal.groupValue1
                       }
```

you create an anonymous type and not a `PlainBrgMetric` object.

**Provided that** `PlainBrgMetric` has at least the same four properties as the anonymou's type properties, you create, you could make a quick fix:

```
(metric, universal) => new PlainBrgMetric 
                       {
                           MetricID = metric.metricID,
                           ProgramLOBID = metric.programLOBID,
                           Label = metric.label,
                           GroupValue1 = universal.groupValue1
                       }
```

**Otherwise** you have to declare another type with these four properties and change both the signature of your method and the type you create above for each result of the join.

I didn't mention the alternative of the `dynamic` object, since I assumed from your code that you want to return a collection of strongly typed objects.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it you must return a list of `PlainBrgMetric`, what you are returning is a list of anonymous objects.

You should edit your code as follows:

```
public List<PlainBrgMetric> GetPlainBrgMetricProgram(long programLOBID) 
{
    var query = _context.metrics.Join(_context.universals,
                                  m => m.metricID,
                                  u => u.orderByAsc,
                                 (metric, universal) => new PlainBrgMetric
                                 {
                                     //Populate the object properties
                                     ...
                                 }).ToList();
    return query;
}
```